# Issues installing smbclient and openssh-server on 18.04.2

Tags: 18.04, openssh, smb

Complete Linux newb trying to get Ubuntu going so that I can learn.  I'm getting the following errors when I try to install the SMB client and Open SSh server on a fresh install of 18.04.2.  Can anyone help?

```
root@ubuntu:~# apt-get install smbclient
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 smbclient : Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2) but 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.6 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.



root@ubuntu:~# apt-get install openssh-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openssh-server : Depends: openssh-client (= 1:7.6p1-4)
                  Depends: openssh-sftp-server but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: ssh-import-id but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy samba-libs openssh-client` to the question. Did you forget to run `sudo apt update`?

Answer (score 4):

For the issue for openssh-server, I solved with this :
`sudo apt-get install openssh-client=1:7.6p1-4` (copied the version mentioned in the message to install the required dependency version manually)

Answer (score 2):

It worked after running these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-client=1:8.2p1-4
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run "apt-get install -f." If that does not work, run "apt update," "apt-get update," and then run "apt-get install -f" again. In order to monitor broken packages in the future, install Synaptic by running "apt install synaptic." When Synaptic launches, it will notify you of broken packages in the bottom of the window.

Answer (score 0):

openssh-client will be installed automatically as been a dependency. So purge it first and do the openssh-server install.

> sudo apt purge openssh-client

and

> sudo apt-get install openssh-server